# Django: add context to response using decorator

Tags: python, django, decorator

Given the following scenario:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def decorator(view):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'foo': 'bar'}
        # Logic ...
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@decorator
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I'd like to have the decorator add a context dictionary to the view, so that the decorated function that is returned looks like this:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, sure. that is possible. There is a lot of view functions decotarors. [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/) you are someones

Comment: This is exactly  what the [ContextProcessors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) are for.

Comment: For all templates: Context processors. For some Views: decorator

Comment: @J0HN Don't context processors get applied to _every_ view? I'm specifically looking for a solution that can be applied on a per-view basis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bunch of searching, I've figured out how to do this in a way that requires no extra cruft in the original function, keeping things DRY. The key is Django's `TemplateResponse` object, which defers rendering of the template until just before the response is sent to the user, opening up opportunities for processing by decorators (and middleware, FWIW).

Here's what it looks like now:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse    

def decorator(view):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        r = view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        r.context_data = {'foo': 'bar'}
        return r.render()
    return wrapper

@decorator
def index(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: You're right, but just be careful though because a response isn't always a TemplateResponse.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible the way you currently have your function written, but you could do something like the following for the same behavior:

```
from django.shortcuts import render    

def decorator(view):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'foo': 'bar'}
        args = args + (context,)
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper    

@decorator
def index(request, *args):
    return render(request, 'index.html', *args)
```

This will cause the decorator to add your `context` dictionary to the end of the positional arguments that are passed into `index()`, which are then passed onto `render()`.